# how to add both date and time picker in dash application

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I am building small web application, data has both date and time values my date_time column looks like this "'2023-06-07 19:05:24" I want to include time range  picker along with date range picker how to do it in dash application so far i used this code

```
       html.Div(
                                className='date-picker-container',
                                children=[
                                    dcc.DatePickerRange(
                                        id='date-picker',
                                        start_date=df['date_time'].min().date(),
                                        end_date=df['date_time'].max().date(),
                                        min_date_allowed=df['date_time'].min().date(),
                                        max_date_allowed=df['date_time'].max().date(),
                                        initial_visible_month=df['date_time'].max().date(),
                                        display_format='YYYY-MM-DD',
                                    )
                                ]
                            )
```

and here is my callback

```
@app.callback(
    [Output('card', 'children'), Output('card1', 'children'), Output('card2', 'children')],
    [Input('table-selection', 'value'), Input('date-picker', 'start_date'), Input('date-picker', 'end_date')]
)
def update_card(table_name, start_date, end_date):
    if not table_name or not start_date or not end_date:
        return '', '', ''

    start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(days=0)  # Add one day to include end date

    query = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE date_time >= '{start_date}' AND date_time < '{end_date}'"
    cursor.execute(query)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[col[0] for col in cursor.description])
    print(df.to_string())
    cycle_count = 0
    previous_state = None
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        current_state = row["IGN"]
        if previous_state == "On" and current_state == "Off":
            cycle_count += 1
        previous_state = current_state

    cycle_count1 = 0
    previous_state1 = None
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        current_state1 = row["IGN"]
        if previous_state1 == "Off" and current_state1 == "On":
            cycle_count1 += 1
        previous_state1 = current_state1

    df = df[(df['IGN'] == 'On') & (df['GPS'] == 'On')]
    df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Odometer'])
    df1 = df2[df2['Odometer'] != 0]
    df1["Odometer"] = df1["Odometer"].diff()
    df3 = df1.groupby(df1.date_time.dt.date)['Odometer'].sum()
    result = df3.sum() / len(df3) * 0.001
    formatted_num = "{:.2f}".format(result)


    card_content = html.Div(
        className="result-card",
        children=[
            html.H4("Average Km/day", className="card-title"),
            html.H3(formatted_num, className="card-value")
        ]
    )

    return card_content
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom RangeSider with custom mark, step, min and max for it like this:

```py
html.Div(
    className='date-picker-container',
    children=[
        dcc.DatePickerRange(
            id='date-picker',
            start_date=df['date_time'].min().date(),
            end_date=df['date_time'].max().date(),
            min_date_allowed=df['date_time'].min().date(),
            max_date_allowed=df['date_time'].max().date(),
            initial_visible_month=df['date_time'].max().date(),
            display_format='YYYY-MM-DD',
        ),
        dcc.RangeSlider(
            id='time-range-picker',
            marks={i: {'label': str(i)} for i in range(24)},
            min=0,
            max=23,
            step=1,
            value=[0, 23]
        )
    ]
)
```

And then add `Input('time-range-picker', 'value')` to callback decorator and the query will be like this:

```py
start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(days=0)  # Add one day to include end date

start_time = datetime.combine(start_date, datetime.min.time()) + timedelta(hours=time_range[0])
end_time = datetime.combine(start_date, datetime.min.time()) + timedelta(hours=time_range[1])

query = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE date_time >= '{start_time}' AND date_time < '{end_time}'"
```

So the final `update_card` will be :

```py
@app.callback(
    [Output('card', 'children'), Output('card1', 'children'), Output('card2', 'children')],
    [Input('table-selection', 'value'), Input('date-picker', 'start_date'), Input('date-picker', 'end_date'),
     Input('time-range-picker', 'value')]
)
def update_card(table_name, start_date, end_date, time_range):
    if not table_name or not start_date or not end_date:
        return '', '', ''

    start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(days=0)  # Add one day to include end date

    start_time = datetime.combine(start_date, datetime.min.time()) + timedelta(hours=time_range[0])
    end_time = datetime.combine(start_date, datetime.min.time()) + timedelta(hours=time_range[1])

    query = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE date_time >= '{start_time}' AND date_time < '{end_time}'"
    cursor.execute(query)
    # Rest of your code...
```

Comment: this error iam getting Unresolved reference 'time_range'

Comment: @appu I updated my code, you have to add time_range in the update_card

Comment: @appu if it helped please select the correct answer and give an upvote to support me, thanks

Comment: output  i am getting single record not getting date based on time and date range selection

Comment: first check start_datetime and end_datetime if they are as you select in the frontend then check the query to see if it is as you want, then check the output of query

Comment: i checked all but not getting the response for selected range

Comment: So you have to debug, data in the database, query and etc.